# Update multiple data using one function in firebase function

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm making a user points system app and right now I'm attempting to make a functions that increases all the user points by 10% whenever the function is called once.

I've tried using the realtime database triggering method and they required the users to create, write, delete or update the database in order for the functions to trigger.

```
export const userVerification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userId}')
.onUpdate((change, context)=>{
    const before = change.before.val()
    const after = change.after.val()
    if (updatePoints(before.points) === after.points) {
        console.log("BEFORE TEXT: " + before.points)
        console.log("AFTER TEXT: " + after.points)
        console.log("Points didn't change")
        return null
    }
    console.log("BEFORE TEXT: " + before.points)
    console.log("AFTER TEXT: " + after.points)
    const points = updatePoints(after.points)
    return change.after.ref.update({points})
})
```

[This is the function that I used to update my points]

```
function updatePoints(points: string): string {
    const floatPoints: number = parseFloat(points);
    const totalPoints = (floatPoints + floatPoints * 0.1).toFixed(2);
    console.log(totalPoints)
    return totalPoints
}
```

Is there a way for me to call a method once using Firebase Function and let the function increase all my user points in a go?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using a **https on call** function would be your solution. You can create a function similar to what you have now, but you do not have to rely on a database change for it to run - you can call it directly from your frontend.

[Check this out for more information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable)

You can also do **batched writes** which allows you to define multiple database references that execute writes to the database and then execute them all at once.

[More info here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes)